# Re-arrange a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have data that comes from the database looking like:

```
[
  {
    ID: 1,
    UPC: 11111,
    Qty: 1,
    Price: 1.99
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    UPC: 11111,
    Qty: 2,
    Price: 1.99
  },
  {
    ID: 3,
    UPC: 22222,
    Qty: 1,
    Price: 9.99
  },
  {
    ID: 4,
    UPC: 11111,
    Qty: 3,
    Price: 1.99
  },
  {
    ID: 5,
    UPC: 22222,
    Qty: 9,
    Price: 9.99
  }
]
```

Within the page, *if* they click a button, I need to rearrange it to look like this:

```
[
  {
    UPC: 11111,
    Qty: 6,
    Price: 1.99
  },
  {
    UPC: 22222,
    Qty: 10,
    Price: 9.99
  }
]
```

How can I convert this?  99% of the time I need the original dataset, so initially returning it like the 2nd dataset is not an option.

TIA.

Comment: You would need to write some code to accomplish this. If you get stuck on a specific part of your implementation, let us know. But as it stands now, it sounds like you just want us to write your code for you, and that doesn't make for a good question.

Comment: @mason I've been trying for a couple of days with different things, all of which were complete flops. I can't figure out how to even get started accomplishing this, which is why I'm posting this in the first place, and was hoping to at least get some pointers / suggestions.

Comment: @BryanFritchie, are you using a programming language to reformat the json data?

Comment: @downshift JavaScript. I found this link that wasn't there when I started this back in January: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730072/reorder-a-json-collection/42911317#42911317  It has got me to semi-correct results so far, but I would guess that there are some jQuery or Underscore functions which are better.

Comment: @BryanFritchie you might want to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42909737/edit) the question and include those possible tags. However, the question's already a few hours old and probably fallen back in the queue and I doubt it will receive any new views. You may want to consider deleting and reposting the question and include those relevant tags. Just a thought. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, after your question I realized maybe I didn't provide as much detail as I thought I did. Guess I was rushing too much to try and get some help.  I'll see about reposting here shortly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the link posted above in the comments, I managed to make this work.  I feel like there is probably a more efficient way using Underscore.js, but since I can't figure it out, this will do.

```
var tmpItems = {};
for (var i = items.length; i--;)
{
  // init an array, if it is not there
  tmpItems[it.All[i]['UPC']] = tmpItems[it.All[i]['UPC']] || [];

  tmpItems[it.All[i]['UPC']]['Qty'] = (tmpItems[it.All[i]['UPC']]['Qty'] || 0) + (it.All[i]['Qty'] || 0);
  tmpItems[it.All[i]['UPC']]['Price'] = (it.All[i]['Price'] || 0);
}

// convert back to an object
var newItems = [];
for (var key in tmpItems)
{
  if (tmpItems.hasOwnProperty(key))
  {
    newItems.push({ 'UPC': key, 'Qty': tmpItems[key]['Qty'], 'Price': tmpItems[key]['Price'] });
  }
}
```